# How to remove all but last 10 files using c++ without using system()

Tags: c++, linux

how to implement system("ls -t1 . | tail -n +11 | xargs rm -rf") without using system(). i want to keep only latest 10 files in my linux folder rest of them should be removed when i call c++ function.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: You read directory content into a container, then sort files by time and delete them starting from 11th or before last 10 depends how you sorted it.

Comment: The readdir() method lets you read the contents of the directory. You can then sort by whatever manner you prefer, then pick which to delete with unlink().

Answer (score 0):

Here's some C++ code that doesn't need to store all entries, but just remembers the oldest 10 and deletes any newer.

As always with code that deletes files **BE CAREFUL THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL DELETE FILES IF YOU RUN IT**

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using pathvec = std::vector<fs::directory_entry>;

struct newer_file {
    bool operator()(const fs::directory_entry& p, const fs::directory_entry& p2)
    {
        return p.last_write_time() < p2.last_write_time();
    }
};

void delete_newest(fs::path directory, int keep_n = 10)
{
    //store N oldest entries, delete any that are newer
    std::priority_queue<fs::directory_entry, pathvec, newer_file> oldestN;
    for (auto entry : fs::directory_iterator(directory))
    {
        oldestN.push(entry);
        if (oldestN.size() > keep_n)
        {
            //careful, recursive delete
            fs::remove_all(oldestN.top());
            oldestN.pop();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "argument needed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    delete_newest(fs::path(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```